# IF no funciona en Bash

Tags: linux, bash

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
#!/bin/bash
    
profesores=$( cat /etc/group | grep profesores | cut -d ":" -f 1)
alumnos=$( cat /etc/group | grep alumnos | cut -d ":" -f 1)
    
if ! getent group profesores; then
    echo "creando grupo profesores...";
    addgroup profesores;
fi

echo $alumnos
    
if [ '$alumnos' != 'alumnos' ]; then
    echo "creando grupo alumnos...";
    addgroup alumnos;
else 
    exit
fi
```

Me gustaría saber por qué no me funciona el if ya que, a pesar de que la condición no se cumple, el programa hace como que sí se cumple. No tiene sentido, me explico:

La salida de este comando: `alumnos=$( cat /etc/group | grep alumnos | cut -d ":" -f 1)` es igual a `alumnos`, entonces a la hora de ejecutar las líneas:

```
if [ '$alumnos' != 'alumnos' ]; then
     echo "creando grupo alumnos...";
     addgroup alumnos;
    else exit
```

el programa tendría que realizar lo siguiente: si `$alumnos` (que su valor es alumnos) no es igual a la cadena de texto "alumnos" entonces crea ese grupo, pero por algún motivo que no entiendo el programa se piensa que no es igual el valor de la variable `$alumnos` (que su valor es alumnos) con la cadena de texto "alumnos" y da igual que en teoría sean iguales porque para el programa es distinto. ¿Por qué motivo sucede esto?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Respuesta corta

Pon comillas dobles a todas tus variables y expansiones

### Respuesta larga

Hay un mecanismo en bash llamado "expansion" (de parametros, variables, tilde, rutas, etc), en el cual las variables se expanden de cierta manera si cumplen ciertas características.

En tu caso estaríamos hablando de una "variable expansion".

Si quieres expandir una variable, que no es más que sustituir el nombre de la variable por el contenido al que hace referencia (y posiblemente hacer otra operación), necesitas tan sólo ponerla tal cual:

```
echo Esta es mi variable: $variable
```

Pero esto puede acarrear ciertos inconvenientes, y es que algunos comandos pueden entender la expansión como parte de sus parámetros:

```
$ var1="-n"
$ echo $var1 hola
$ hola$
```

Por ejemplo, aquí pensaríamos que `echo $var1 hola` imprimiría, "-n hola", pero *no fue así*. Lo que hizo fue imprimir "hola" pero **sin el salto de línea** usual de `echo`.

Esto es porque el contenido de `var1` tiene como valor una cadena que también es parámetro de `echo`, el parámetro `-n`, que provoca que `echo` no ponga su salto de línea.

En otras palabras, con la expansión podemos inyectar código y hacer casi metaprogramación, y esto no siempre es lo que queremos.

La respuesta de @psauleda permite ese tipo de casos, por ejemplo, si tu haces algo como:

```
$ var1='cadena con espacios'; [ $var1 = "prueba" ]
bash: [: too many arguments
```

Tendremos ese error, ya que se evalúa como `[ cadena con espacios = "prueba" ]`, donde cada palabra es tomada como un argumento y por eso tenemos ese error de "demasiados argumentos".

Sin embargo, bash proporciona un mecanismo para evitar o limitar estas expansiones y lo hace a través del entrecomillado (quotting).

Comillas simples *evitan las expansiones*, y comillas dobles *lo limitan* a ciertos caracteres que si se pueden expandir. Además que el entrecomillado hace que los comandos tomen lo entrecomillado como una unidad, no como varias.

Por ejemplo, en tu caso:

```
[ '$alumnos' != 'alumnos' ]
```

Lo que estás haciendo es que la cadena `'$alumnos'` la estás comparando con la cadena `'alumnos'`, y con las comillas simples estás comparando no solo la palabra `alumnos`, sino también el signo de pesos como parte de la cadena, y esto es porque las comillas simples no permiten la sustitución de la variable por su contenido.

Lo que seguramente querías hacer era algo como:

```
[ "$alumnos" != 'alumnos' ]
```

Es decir, con las comillas dobles para que 1) Se pudiera sustituir la variable, 2) Prevenir el splitting dentro del *builtin* `[]`.

Comment: Comprendido muchas gracias por la explicacion

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que sacar la variable $alumnos de las comillas, para que no lo tome como un literal. Es decir, quedaría así:

```
if [ $alumnos != 'alumnos' ]; then
 echo "creando grupo alumnos...";
 addgroup alumnos;
else exit
```

Fuera de las comillas, se sustituye la variable por su valor, dentro devuelve el nombre de la variable, dolar incluido, por lo que no se cumple la condición.